# Definir chave de array associativo

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional, array-associativo

Considere este array:

```
protected $filter = [
    'preco' => 'required;double(1,4)',
    'email' => 'required;email'
];
```

Passo pelo foreach:

```
protected function bootFilterPost() {

    foreach ($this->filter as $key => $value):
        $this->postRules[$key] = preg_split('/(;)/', $value);
    endforeach;

    var_dump($this->postRules);
}
```

e tenho esta saída:

```
array(2) {
  ["preco"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "required"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "double(1,4)"
  }
  ["email"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "required"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "email"
  }
}
```

mas precisaria que saísse dessa forma:

```
array(2) {
  ["preco"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["required"]=>
    string(8) "true"
    ["double"]=>
    string(11) "1,4"
  }
  ["email"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["required"]=>
    string(8) "true"
    ["email"]=>
    string(5) "true"
  }
}
```

ou seja, preciso que o valores sejam inseridos como chaves e a estas o valor em string ("true") ou booleam(true);

Comment: O padrão é sempre este: se for apenas uma palavra, fique `"palavra" => true`, mas se houver parenteses, fique `"palavra" => "parenteses"`? Há mais algum formato que deve ser considerado?

Comment: A sua pergunta não está muito bem definida em termos de output. Lembro que o Laravel tem muitas regras de validação que não acabam em `true`, tais como `min`, `max`, `different`, `digits`, etc...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss exatamente `"palavra" => true` como descrito por você. No caso do valor double(1,4) ficaria `["double"] => "1,4"`. Este seria o formato diferente a ser considerado.

Comment: @Isac, eu criaria uma string e converteria em array, mas não achei uma fórmula para isso!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar de não ter definido as regras todas que interessavam, pois as [validações do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation) são bastante completas e permitem muitas outras coisas que não mencionou, tais como, `unique`, `min`, `max`, `digits`, etc... apresento-lhe uma solução possível.

Esta utiliza um array auxiliar de mapeamento de valores:

```
private $regras = [
    "required"=>true, 
    "email"=>true
];
```

Se o valor a ser considerado estiver neste array o mapeamento é aplicado diretamente, caso contrario tenta ver se o valor tem alguma separação por `(`

```
double(1,4)
```

Ou separação por `:`

```
digits:3
```

Fazendo a respetiva interpretação e aplicação.

Exemplo:

```
protected function bootFilterPost() {

    foreach ($this->filter as $key => $value):
        $arr = preg_split('/(;)/', $value);

        foreach ($arr as $a): //ver cada regra de validação do campo

            //ver se é um que faz parte do array de regras 
            if (array_key_exists ($a, $this->regras)): 
                $this->postRules[$key][$a] = $this->regras[$a];

            elseif (strpos($a, "(") !== false): //ver se tem (
                $split = explode("(", $a); //dividir pelo (
                $this->postRules[$key][$split[0]] = "(" . $split[1];

            elseif (strpos($a, ":") !== false): //ver se tem :
                $split = explode(":", $a); //dividir pelo :
                $this->postRules[$key][$split[0]] = $split[1]; 

            endif;


        endforeach;
    endforeach;

    var_dump($this->postRules);
}
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/G6JXgv)

Comment: Perfeito, esse código abriu a mente para fazer muitas outras coisas.